# Custom parameters in SysLog with Log4J & SLF4J

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, slf4j

I have Log4J with SLF4J working in my app, and right now it logs the request in a standard format and it also sends default information to the syslog. I do both because there is some information that I want with each request logged - account and/or user id making the request, the request method type - post, get, etc.

Is there a way to send the same custom information to the syslog?

From what I have found you can alter the format of the log entry, but you can't append additional information to the syslog as that would screw up the format and may not be pulled into various reporting tools and you can't change the contents of a piece of the log - for example, changing the category to hold the request method type. I was thinking that route so the tools would pick up the data.

Is there a good tool that you can specify the log format and it can parse it, or it handles different log formats? I need to know more about who is doing what where so I need to create custom reports, rather than the standard - how many hits per page, etc.